# How to keep open first section of collapsible div in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a collapsible div which is created with angularjs,here I am able to keep open first section of collapsible div with the help of json array inside script.js,but I want to keep open it in some other way not from json. Here is the code below
https://plnkr.co/edit/nCdGzZYPSTYsMPYf8K9o?p=preview

### HTML

```
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>   
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open($index)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### SCRIPT

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (index) {
    $scope.groups[index].isOpen = !$scope.groups[index].isOpen;
    $scope.closeOthers(index);
  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (index) {
    for(var i = 0; i  < $scope.groups.length; i++) {
       if (i !== index)
        $scope.groups[i].isOpen = false;
    }
  }

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',

      isOpen: true,
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a']
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',

      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',

    }
  ];

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `angular.forEach` and try this:
JS:

```
 $scope.groups[0].expanded = true;
   $scope.expanded = function(select) {
             var boolexpansion = !select.expanded;
             angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(n) {
             n.expanded = false;
            });
            if(boolexpansion) {
            select.expanded = !select.expanded;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="group in groups track by $index">
      <button ng-if="!group.expanded" ng-click="expanded(group);">+</button>  
      <button ng-if="group.expanded" ng-click="expanded(group);">-</button>  
      {{ group.title }}
</div>
   <div ng-if="group.expanded" ng-repeat-end="" >
   {{group.content}}
   </div>
</div>
```

example: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rCx31w3q5i52brTx